# Superfish Menu Wraps in IE9 and Mac Safari

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9, superfish

I have implemented Superfish in a pretty basic custom Wordpress theme. The padding and / or spacing of the top level menu items is off in IE9 and also Mac Safari. I can't figure out what is causing the problem or how to fix it without affecting the browsers where it already renders properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd forget about using a menu plugin and use the WP3 menu system. There are no IE issues and no extra JS needed. And it's probably easier to implement than the plugin you're using. Grab the code from twentyten or twentyeleven.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu and http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide